# Where are the routes for Gii defined in Yii framework?

Tags: php, url-routing, yii, yii-components

I created a Yii application in the webroot. I enabled the Gii module and modify the .htaccess to remove the index.php part in the url.

I also have the `urlManager` component defined in the config/main.php configuration file.

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'showScriptName' => FALSE,
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
        )
)
```

When I enter `http://www.mydomain.com/gii` in the browser, I get redirected to `http://www.mydomain.com/gii/default/login`.

Obviously, there is no matching url `rules` in the `urlManager`. Does this mean that when Yii cannot find any matching url rule, it will then start looking for a matching module?

Comment: ¿What is the problem?... ¿Is there a problem? The redirection to http://www.mydomain.com/gii/default/login was unexpected to you? ¿What did you expected?

Comment: @Alfredo Castañeda García the problem is, `gii` is a module name, `default` is a controller name, and `login` is the action. `gii/default/login` still works even I don't have a rule pattern that matches it, this is where I feel strange about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bobo, yes, it does look like Yii starts looking through matching modules:

```
yii/framework/gii/GiiModule.php, Line 43
* http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=gii
*
* If your application is using path-format URLs with some customized URL rules, you may need to add
* the following URLs in your application configuration in order to access GiiModule:
* <pre>
* 'components'=>array(
*     'urlManager'=>array(
*         'urlFormat'=>'path',
*         'rules'=>array(
*             'gii'=>'gii',
*             'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
*             'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
*             ...other rules...
*         ),
*     )
* )
* </pre>
```

Looks like it starts with the normal rules and then moves on down to trying additional modules (and their controller/actions) after that.  Seems to be using the module ID (gii in this case) as the first part of it all.

On further research, yes, that's the case.  See the [Yii Module page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module#using-module) for more info.

Comment: Sure, glad to help.  Hadn't really thought through how it worked until I saw your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you mean?? Gii is a module and the URL is right you have the default because the defaultController proprerty in CWebModule is 'default' you can extend Gii and customize it if you want.